# Table position at bottom of PDF page

Tags: java, alignment

I have made a Table object and it is displaying on my PDF correctly but I want to position the table so that it is at the bottom of the page. I keep attempting to call

```
Table table = new Table(3);
table.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
```

but that doesn't seem to change the position of my table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since this is not part of the standard Java JDK, you might want to give more context information (what library do you use to create pdf? What library does Table come from? etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Can you say some thing more about your table, means which table it is? (x.y.z.Table) which are those x and y ?
If the table is yours, tell me which is the super class. and Which LayOut you are using.
Are you talking about javafx table or swing table.